# Despite stack solver, Could not find module `Test.Hspec'

Tags: haskell, dependencies, haskell-stack

This is my `stack.yaml` file declaring `hspec` as a extra dependency:

```
# Specifies the GHC version and set of packages available (e.g., lts-3.5, nightly-2015-09-21, ghc-7.10.2)
resolver: lts-3.8  

# Local packages, usually specified by relative directory name
packages:
- '.'

# Packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps:
- hspec-2.2.0
```

when I run `stack solver` it says there is no change to be done:

```
root@5d7daa2aec0a:/src/test_stack/a-test/src# stack solver
This command is not guaranteed to give you a perfect build plan
It's possible that even with the changes generated below, you will still need to do some manual tweaking
Asking cabal to calculate a build plan, please wait
No needed changes found

To automatically modify your stack.yaml file, rerun with '--modify-stack-yaml'
```

this is my source file (only to check that I could use Hspec with stack):

```
module Main where

import Test.Hspec


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "hello world"
```

and when I run `stack build` I get:

2015-10-05 22:24:08.450413: [warn]     Could not find module `Test.Hspec' @(stack_Bp003b8iWaELtdr693pSPs:Stack.Build.Execute src/Stack/Build/Execute.hs:1241:35)

I thought `stack solver` was ensuring that extra dependencies are ok.

What I am doing wrong ? 
It's the first time I use stack.

Comment: The first thing to check would be whether you have added *hspec* to the cabal file.

Comment: Specifically, look for the line `build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5`, add a comma, and write `hspec` there. Then try `stack build` again.

Comment: @duplode this means that stack does not replace using cabal directly for managing dependencies ? I thought so, that it was managing cabal for me.

Comment: @StephaneRolland The confusion is due to "cabal" having multiple meanings. stack replaces cabal-install, the tool which install and manages dependencies. However, it does not replace Cabal, the packaging system. The projects you configure with stack are still Cabal-compatible packages, and stack uses the information in the .cabal files. For instance, if you remove *hspec* from the extra-deps, add it to the .cabal file build-depends and run `stack solver --modify-stack-yaml`, stack will happily add it back.

Comment: I thought there would be a duplicate, but none of the existing questions under [haskell-stack] fits exactly. That being so, I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While stack replaces cabal-install, the command line tool for building and installing packages, it still uses the Cabal packaging infrastructure. In particular, that means projects built with stack are still Cabal-compatible packages with .cabal files, and all of their dependencies should be listed in the `build-depends` section of the .cabal file with appropriate version ranges. That holds even if the dependency is also specified in the `stack.yaml` file `extra-deps` field, as that field serves a different purpose (namely, giving stack an exact version to use when building the package).